# How to copy a directory from a url using ant script?

Tags: svn, url, ant, copy, trunk

My requirement is to copy a particular directory from the trunk of SVN to my present or local machine and then continue with my execution. Could you kindly suggest as to how i go about it? The get command only  copies files and not directories.
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can [export](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#export) using [svn ant task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html)

Editorial:  It's a bad idea to have your build script deal with source control.  I believe it's a truism that if you're wanting to use svn ant you're doing something wrong.

You should get the source (and the build script (which is source)) from svn and then execute your build script.  Mixing them up is a bad plan, keep these concerns separate.  You're going to have issues when you move from svn to git or hg (which you should consider) if your build is incestuously tied to your source control.  It's also going to get complicated when you work from branches - you're going to always pull in the trunk in your build.  This is even worse if you tag the source, and then checkout or export the tag.